# relational operator error while using multiple condition in where clause

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a date column and need to check couple of conditions for below scenario..
but looks like I am doing something wrong and thus getting error

```
scenario:
If EmpBonusDate column is null or
if (sysdate-EmpBonusDate >= some constant number) then return 1 else 0
```

-- I am multiplying output of (sysdate-EmpBonusDate) by 24 so, I can get a number which I can compare to check >= 
condition with constant number.

this is what my sql looks like

```
Select count(1) from employee emp where
Emp.IsActive = '1'
and (sysdate - emp.EmpBonusDate) * 24 >= 30 -- this works
-- or nvl(emp.EmpBonusDate,1) -- if I add or clause, I get [ORA-00920] invalid relational operator error....
```

any clue what I am doing wrong and how can I get the 1 or 0 for above mentioned scenario

Comment: Can you try with and `Emp.IsActive = '1' and ((sysdate - emp.EmpBonusDate) * 24 >= 30 or emp.EmpBonusDate is null)` ?

Comment: Getting error or not extracting rows?

Comment: @WoAiNii - you can post this as answer.. I will accept it.. working as expected..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With syntax `or nvl(emp.EmpBonusDate,1)` you're missing relationship, because you're not comparing that value with something.

You can replace your `where` clause with this

```
Emp.IsActive = '1' and ((sysdate - emp.EmpBonusDate) * 24 >= 30 or emp.EmpBonusDate is null)
```

that's equivalent to your if clause.